# AVAudioSequencer - How to be notified when playback ends

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am using `AVAudioSequencer` with `AVAudioEngine` and I am having just one single problem: how do I get the sequencer to notify when a track or file has reached its end?
I know there is an `AVAudioPlayerNodeCompletionHandler` thing, but then, `AVAudioSequencer` is not derived from `AVAudioPlayerNode`.

So far, the only thing I could think of was periodically comparing the `currentPositionInBeats` property in `AVAudioSequencer` with  the `lengthInBeats` property in `AVMusicTrack` (the `isPlaying` property in `AVAudioSequencer` just doesn't go false when the sequencer goes beyond this limit,) but I don't like polling.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation now, and I don't see any answers on this still. @filiOS, did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I worked around this issue (I'm using AudioKit's AppleSequencer, which is a layer on top of AVAudioSequencer, and has a MIDICallbackInstrument, and the callback handles the playing of the various instruments and tracks)

I added another track to the sequencer, a "control" track, and to that track I added a special MIDI note (it doesn't matter which, as the control track interprets it) at the end of the sequence. In my MIDI callback, every time I come across this MIDI note, I increment the runLoop, and when it equals the loopCount, I go ahead and stop the sequence (and set an isPlaying variable to false). Any UI element can then monitor this variable and also update itself appropriately. This worked out great for me.